Inaccuracy in the C standard in the description of integer rank conversions?
C standard say (6.3.1.1 Boolean, characters, and integers):

1 Every integer type has an integer conversion rank defined as follows:

No two signed integer types shall have the same rank, even if they have the same
representation.
The rank of a signed integer type shall be greater than the rank of any signed integer
type with less precision.
The rank of long long int shall be greater than the rank of long int, which
shall be greater than the rank of int, which shall be greater than the rank of short
int, which shall be greater than the rank of signed char.
The rank of any unsigned integer type shall equal the rank of the corresponding
signed integer type, if any.
The rank of any standard integer type shall be greater than the rank of any extended
integer type with the same width.
The rank of char shall equal the rank of signed char and unsigned char.
The rank of _Bool shall be less than the rank of all other standard integer types.
The rank of any enumerated type shall equal the rank of the compatible integer type
(see 6.7.2.2).
The rank of any extended signed integer type relative to another extended signed
integer type with the same precision is implementation-defined, but still subject to the
other rules for determining the integer conversion rank.
For all integer types T1, T2, and T3, if T1 has greater rank than T2 and T2 has
greater rank than T3, then T1 has greater rank than T3.


This means that in the integer type system there cannot be two types (signed or unsigned) with the same rank. However, further:

The following may be used in an expression wherever an int or unsigned int may
be used:

An object or expression with an integer type (other than int or unsigned int)
whose integer conversion rank is less than or equal to the rank of int and
unsigned int.


How is it possible that some lesser type will have the same rank?

Maybe I'm missing something, but in the clause "The rank of any unsigned integer type shall equal the rank of the corresponding signed integer type, if any", you seem to be ignoring the "if any" at the end? The bits that you've bolded don't mean that no two unsigned integer types can have the same rank, only that no two unsigned integer types can have the same rank if they both have corresponding signed integer types. (Consider e.g. uintptr_t.)

It's not saying "lesser type". "same rank" means you can, for example, use compatible enums in integer expressions. You can also use chars in integer expressions, because they can expand to integer types of the same rank. You cannot use long longs for obvious reasons.

"object or expression" - perhaps referring to an expression having equal  rank as an object.  Either way, it is not "inaccurate" since it also says "less than or equal", which is valid even if the equal set were empty.  Also there are type aliases and enums that can have equal rank.

In my opinion, the standard should not give different interpretations, in the phrase "less than or equal to" the word "equal to" is excluded by the clause "No two signed integer types shall have the same rank, even if they have the same representation." where (further) The rank of any unsigned integer type shall equal the rank of the corresponding signed integer type, if any. By the way, "if any" is really confusing.

Your "this means that" assertion is directly contradicted by text you yourself bolded.

@jthill, What is the contradiction? I read exactly as it is written in the standard. Can you give an example when two signed types will have the same rank? Or two unsigned ones?

Then I think you left off a "both" in your assertion. "two types( both signed or both unsigned).

An enumerated type may have the same rank as int but not be an int. The following demonstrates this in the rules of the C standard.
C 2018 6.2.5 17 says:

The type char, the signed and unsigned integer types, and the enumerated types are collectively called integer types…

So an enumerated type is an integer type. It is not, however, a signed integer type or an unsigned integer type, as those are specified to be the standard and extended integer types in 6.2.5 4:

There are five standard signed integer types, designated as signed char, short int, int, long int, and long long int… There may also be implementation-defined extended signed integer types. The standard and extended signed integer types are collectively called signed integer types.

and 6:

… The standard and extended unsigned integer types are collectively called unsigned integer types.

So, the integer types may be partitioned into four subsets: char, signed integer types, unsigned integer types, and enumerated types.
6.7.2.2 4 says:

Each enumerated type shall be compatible with char, a signed integer type, or an unsigned integer type. The choice of type is implementation-defined…

So an enumerated type is something other than a char, a signed integer type, or an unsigned integer type but it is compatible with one of those. Since it is not a signed integer type or unsigned integer type, it is not subject to any of the rank rules in 6.3.1.1 1 about signed integer types or unsigned integer types. The only rank rule that applies to it is this one:

The rank of any enumerated type shall equal the rank of the compatible integer type (see 6.7.2.2).

Thus we see that there may be an enumerated type that is compatible with int and therefore has the same rank as int. Then an object or expression of this type is “An object or expression with an integer type (other than int or unsigned int)” whose integer conversion rank equals the rank of int.

This is the best explanation I could get!


C17 §6.2.5 ¶17 The type char, the signed and unsigned integer types, and the enumerated types are collectively called integer types. [...]

So, depending on the platform, an object of an enum type could be an "object or expression with an integer type (other than int or unsigned int) whose integer conversion rank is equal to the rank of int and unsigned int."
The standard also refers to the types defined by stdint.h as integer types. ("The header <stdint.h> declares sets of integer types having [...]") So int32_t could also qualify.

About enums it seems very true!
But int32_t is an alias for int, entered keyword typedef, and does not introduce a new type (int and int32_t are the same type)

int32_t is a typedef for either int or another standard integer type or it is a typedef for an extended integer type. Either way, it is subject to the rank rules and cannot be an example of a type that is not int but has the same rank as int.
